# Expand columns into dates in R

Tags: r

I have data structured in the following way:

- date            H01     H02 ... H48
- 01-Jan-19 15,328  15,273 ... 5,241
- 02-Jan-19 17,412  17,474 ... 7,625

H01 to H48 represent values each 30 min within the same day.
This does not follow the principles of tidy data.

I would like to have only two columns:

- date             value
- 01/01/2019 00:00   15,328
- 01/01/2019 00:30  15,273
- 01/01/2019 01:00   ...

How can I obtain this in R?

Thank you!

Comment: Post a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package tidyr makes this pretty easy with the `gather` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(Date = c("01-Jan-19", "02-Jan-19"),
             H01 = c(15328, 17412),
             H02 = c(15273, 17474))

times.df <- tibble(Code = c("H01", "H02"),
                       Time = c("00:30", "1:00"))

gather(df, key = "Code", value = "Value", -Date) %>%
  left_join(times.df) %>%
  mutate(DateTime = dmy_hm(paste(Date, Time, sep = " "))) 

# Joining, by = "Code"
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# Date      Code  Value Time  DateTime           
# <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dttm>             
#   1 01-Jan-19 H01   15328 00:30 2019-01-01 00:30:00
# 2 02-Jan-19 H01   17412 00:30 2019-01-02 00:30:00
# 3 01-Jan-19 H02   15273 1:00  2019-01-01 01:00:00
# 4 02-Jan-19 H02   17474 1:00  2019-01-02 01:00:00
```

Comment: Ok, this is helpful, how do I convert now the 01-Jan-19 H02 to 01/01/2019 00:30?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to do that and to change the data type to date-time, in case you need it that way for your analysis.